# Default Value TextArea Mysterious Spaces

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

## I have

a text area. I load a default value from a file into it (d5), but for some reasons, it give me so many space in front of that value.

[image]

## I tried

**PHP**

```
    $filename = public_path().'/file/external/header.txt';
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $header = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
```

**Blade**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Description</label>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <textarea name="description" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Desciption">
            {{$description}}
        </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

## Try#2

Take off class `form-group` from my parent div.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Description</label>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <textarea name="description" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Desciption">
      {{$description}}
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

I got

[image]

---

## Try#3

Take off class `form-control` from my text-area element.

```
<div class="">
  <label class="col-sm-12 control-label">Description</label>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <textarea name="description" class="" rows="5" placeholder="Desciption">
      {{$description}}
    </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

I got

[image]

---

- Why does it do that ?
- Did I do anything wrong here ?
- How do I stop that ?

Comment: It is most likely due to your CSS.

Comment: Try and put `<textarea>...{{$description}}</textarea>` on one line in your code.. still have spaces?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have indentations in the html. **ANYTHING** that appears between the opening/closing `<textarea>` tags becomes PART of the text area:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <textarea name="description" class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Desciption">
                                                                                        ^
        {{$description}}
^^^^^^^^                ^
    </textarea>
^^^^
</div>
```

The `^` mark the spaces you're getting. If you don't want those spaces, then don't have them:

```
<textarea>foo</textarea>
```

v.s.

```
<textarea>
          ^--line break at start of textarea content
    foo
^^^^----spaces
       ^--another line break
</textarea>
```

Comment: You're right ! It works now. :)